# TSQL Select Clause with Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a basic select statement that is getting me a list of types that are stored in the database:

```
SELECT teType
FROM   BS_TrainingEvent_Types
WHERE source = @source
FOR    XML PATH ('options'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('types')
```

My table contains a type column and a source column.

There is a record in that table where I need to include it for two separate sources but I can't create a separate record for it.

```
**Table  Data**

type   |  source   
test      users
test2     members
test3     admins
```

I need a case statement to be able to say `IF source = admins also give me the type test2`.

Does this make sense and is it possible to do with a basic select?

**Update**
I came up with this temp solution but I still think there is a better way to handle this.:

```
DECLARE @tmp AS TABLE (
QID VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO @tmp (QID)
SELECT DISTINCT qid
FROM   tfs_adhocpermissions;

SELECT t.QID,
       emp.FirstName,
       emp.LastName,
       emp.NTID,
       (SELECT accessKey
        FROM   TFS_AdhocPermissions AS p
        WHERE  p.QID = t.QID
        FOR    XML PATH ('key'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('keys'))
FROM   @tmp AS t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.EmployeeTable AS emp
       ON t.QID = emp.QID
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: FYI, it's a CASE *expression*, not a CASE *statement*.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--create temp table for testing
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#BS_TrainingEvent_Types') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #BS_TrainingEvent_Types
SELECT  [type] ,
        [source]
INTO    #BS_TrainingEvent_Types
FROM    ( VALUES ( 'test', 'users'), ( 'test2', 'members'),
        ( 'test3', 'admins') ) t ( [type], [source] ) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--final query
DECLARE @Source VARCHAR(10) = 'users'

IF @Source = 'admins' 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  [Type]
        FROM    #BS_TrainingEvent_Types
        WHERE   source = @source
                OR [type] = 'test2'
        FOR     XML PATH('options') ,
                    TYPE ,
                    ELEMENTS ,
                    ROOT('types')
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  [Type]
        FROM    #BS_TrainingEvent_Types
        WHERE   source = @source
        FOR     XML PATH('options') ,
                    TYPE ,
                    ELEMENTS ,
                    ROOT('types')

    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sq.teType
from (
    SELECT t.teType
    FROM   BS_TrainingEvent_Types t
    WHERE t.source = @source
    union all
    SELECT t.teType
    FROM   BS_TrainingEvent_Types t
    WHERE @source = 'admins' and t.source = 'members'
) sq
FOR XML PATH ('options'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('types');
```

Though normally it would be better to introduce an additional table that would store these relationships, so that the whole idea would be more expandable.